# Как генерировать действительно рандомное число в Android?

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа

Делаю выбор случайного элемента из списка. Всё работает, однако мне кажется, что генерируются псевдослучайные числа. Как генерировать реально случайные числа в Java для Android?

```
int index = 0; 
Random r = new Random();
index = r.nextInt(list.size() - 1);
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам это действительно нужно? Согласно [этому ответу](http://stackoverflow.com/a/381043/3432401), можно воспользоваться сайтом http://random.org. В ответе также указана ссылка на библиотеку, отвечающую за работу с этим сайтом. Не смотрел её код/документацию, но, думаю, её можно "прикрутить" и к Android-приложению.

Comment: Реально раздражает когда ты делаешь рандом а он через n-циклов выдает тот же элемент списка.. Насчет либы - не могли бы подсказать как его прикрутить *

Comment: "через n-циклов выдает тот же элемент списка" - так если вы генерируете случайное число, то рано или поздно сгенерируется такое, которое уже было. В чём тут проблема? Если вам нужно выдать все элементы списка по одному разу в случайном порядке, то это совсем другой вопрос.  По поводу библиотеки этой - нет, не могу: я ей никогда не пользовался. Так что по поводу неё либо кто-то другой ответит, либо вам придётся разбираться самостоятельно.

Comment: Настоящего рандома не существует в плане программирования вообще. Да и в жизни мало рандома, если задуматься. Во всех языках функции генерации рандомных чисел работают по очень простым, но, обычно, хорошо продуманным формулам. Тем не менее, эти числа все равно псевдорандомны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать класс SecureRandom

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html
https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/224285/

"java.security.SecureRandom
SecureRandom похож на java.util.Random в том смысле, что также возвращает 4-байтовое значение. SecureRandom криптографически более надежен" (С)

```
SecureRandom srand = new SecureRandom();
int shouldDraw = srand.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не с той стороны подошли к задаче. Как вам верно указали в комментах ваша проблема не в "ненастоящем рандоме", а том, что вам надо избежать генерации повторяющихся значений, которые служат для получения данных из списка.

Эту задачу надо решать иначе. Например - перемешать список и брать элементы по порядку.

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
for(E e: list){
    //делаем что-то
}
```